# Does heavy usage affect SESSIONS?

Tags: php, session

I have a school web site that I developed in PHP/MySQL. One of my manager complaints that system automatically logs him out after some time. The working hours of that manager is during **peak usage of the website**.

My question is if a lot of people get login at the same time, will this cause SESSION Timeout/Auto logout or something like that ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the garbage collector has a default session timeout of 1440 seconds.

You can either raise the timeout, or just drop any AJAX call once every 10min, in order to reset the timeout... that's called "session stretching".

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068744/php-session-timeout) an answer on how to control session timeout.

Comment: well, ordinary it's intended that they timeout -
but asynchronous clients need to stay connected.