# I want to keep session alive for 10 min. and then unset or destroy it

Tags: php, session-timeout

If a person idles for 10 minutes then I want the page expired -> user has to login again to continue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068744/php-session-timeout

Comment: This is very basic and a visit to php.net would solve our problem.

Comment: thanx @subirkumarsao for providing me useful link.....thanx buddy ths link wil definitely solve my problem......:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime","600");
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if( time() - $_SESSION['login_time'] > 600)
{
    header("Location:login.php");
}
```

This will check if the session has  been running for more than 600 seconds (10 minutes).

Of course first you have to store:

```
$_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
```

when the session is created.

Comment: But Ankit wants session to expire **when user is idle** for 10 mins and not after 10 mins of login. I guess, if your answer is implemented then user will be redirected to login page after 10 mins, no matter user is active or idle.

Comment: mmm yes the title fooled me. In this case i suppose jquery is the only option http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/