# Logging out too quickly with UserCake

Tags: session, usercake

I am being logged out too quickly; I'm guessing, 30 minutes +/-.

If it matters, this website is hosted on a HostGator shared account. The version of UserCake that is used is '2.0.2'.

I added the following to the php.ini file that is in this particular site's root folder (public_html/mysite.com).

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```

But the problem persists. Is there a setting in UserCake's files somewhere to adjust the automatic log out?

Answer (score 1):

1. One another way to adjust logging time settings is `Server -> Settings -> Features -> General -> Login cookie validity`.

> 2.On ProcessMaker you have to change the following parameters on your php.ini in order to modify the session time out
>
> `session.gc_maxlifetime`
> `session.cache_expire`
> `session.cache_limiter` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15767604/5377037)

Comment: Hi, session.gc_maxlifetime is set to 86400 as stated in my post (and I confirmed this with phpinfo). Cache Expire is currently set to 180 (minutes) and I also confirmed this with phpinfo(). I am not sure what you mean by "Server -> ... -> Login cookie validity"; I could not find similar in HostGator's cpanel. Regarding session.cache_expire, according to a comment on php.net "Whatever you set this setting to, it won't change how long sessions live on your server." Lastly, I am not using processMaker. It is a custom-coded site. Appreciate the guesses. Willing to explore more guesses.

Comment: @JohnR I have edited answer. See the Edit (HostGator):

Comment: 'V3' of what? V3 of Cpanel? If that is what you mean, I am not certain which version of cpanel HostGator uses, but the bottom of the cpanel page says, "cPanel, Inc.  70.0.59" (I am not sure if that is the cpanel version). In any event, I did not find 'Utilities' nor it's subpart 'Manage Admins' in cPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you restarted the server after making changes to php.ini file.

I am not sure about the server used. If it is apache, please use the command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Command may vary with Operating System or Web server used.