# How to tie a session expiration to a cookie expiration?

Tags: php, apache, session-cookies

In PHP, how can I make a cookie that lasts exactly as long as a session exists?

Scenario:
A website consists of pages, some are PHP scripts which are executed, such as `login` and `view cart`. Some are static html files read from a cache by Apache, and PHP is not invoked on these pages.

A sessionID is generated and maintained on any page that runs PHP. The session exists regardless of whether the user is actually logged in. The session stores whether the user is logged in or not. The browser only has a sessionID cookie.

A cached page should show either a `log in` or a `log out` button depending on whether the user is logged in or not. PHP is not invoked on cached pages, so the session values can not be read here. A small JavaScript function must be used to check a IsLoggedIn cookie.

Problem:
If the user logs in, PHP can set a cookie that JavaScript reads. Good. If the user explicitly logs out with the log out button, the cookie can be expired. Good.

BUT- if the user leaves the computer, his session expires x seconds from his last interaction with a PHP powered page, while his cookie expires y seconds from when it was created. This can result in one timing out before the other.

Is there a way to synchronize the two, so that they always expire together?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your sessions in the database so you have more control over them and use use ajax set on a time interval to do your checks.  This would make it easier and now you wouldn't need a cookie.  Although if you want a "remember me" function you could use a unuiqe identifier stored in a cookie and `setcookie("nameofcookie", "unuiq md5 value maybe", time()*3600));`

But if you control session in your database you can also control session length and all your logic can be in php.

You can also do this [PHP Session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068744/php-session-timeout)

That is the way I do it.