# How to take md5 of a file in php?

Tags: php

Can you please explain how to take md5 of a file using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey mate looks like quick search will find heaps about this check this out

[PHP Session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068744/php-session-timeout)

first, store the last time the user made a request

```
<?php
   $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
?>
```

in subsequent request, check how long ago they made their previous request (10 minutes in this example)

```
 <?php
    if ($_SESSION['timeout'] + 10 * 60 < time()) {
         // session timed out
    } else {
      // session ok
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: It works, but I think it wont meet my requirement. My requirement is, if a user puts his php page as ideal for 2 mins then I need to destroy a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

I already answered a similar question. This here is after 15 minutes, i suppose you can rewrite it yourself:

```
if(time() - $_SESSION['timestamp'] > 900) { //subtract new timestamp from the old one
    alert("15 Minutes over!");
    unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], $_SESSION['timestamp']);
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = false;
    header("Location: " . index.php); //redirect to index.php
    exit;
} else {
    $_SESSION['timestamp'] = time(); //set new timestamp
}
```