# How to handle expired sessions with XAJAX?

Tags: session, xajax

How do I detect an expired session with xajax so I can redirect users to the login page when that happens or pop a message to let them know?

Comment: Looks like there might be some help [here](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/65486/).  It's a forum post, so it's a bit of a mess, but you might find some useful information there.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068744/php-session-timeout) for session timeout

If session timed out send this:

```
   $response = new xajaxResponse();
   $response->script('location.href="/login";'); // or what ever you want
   return $response;
```