# Expire a PHP session after 1 hour?

Tags: php, authentication, timestamp, timeout, logout

I am new to php coding, and i would really like to figure this login script out.
In my **index.php** file i have this code

```
<?Php
session_start();
include 'check.php';}
?>
```

in my **check.php** file i have this code

```
<?Php
if((isset($_SESSION['userid']) and strlen($_SESSION['userid']) > 4)){

echo "";
}else{
header("Location: login.php");
die();
exit;}
?>
```

How do i create a timeout function to redirect to **logout.php** after 1 hour?

Comment: Possible duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068744/php-session-timeout or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311320/how-to-change-the-session-timeout-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to implement a session timeout of your own.

```
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']=time();
$_SESSION['userid']='Your ID';
```

and add this,

```
<?Php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) {
     // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
     session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
     session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
  include 'check.php';}
?>
```

Comment: where do i enter this code? in the index.php or check.php?

Comment: in index.php before session start

Comment: Here is my code now. <?php
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime","10"); 
session_start();
include 'check.php';?> and it still does not work.

Comment: Then try this,
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600);
session_set_cookie_params(3600);
session_start();

Comment: Current code: ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1);
session_set_cookie_params(1); 
session_start();
include 'check.php';

Comment: The answer can become more valuable if you added some explanation and links to documentation, so the OP and other users can actually learn from it.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont have any more information than what i already have shared with you.